# Different directory showing different ng --version in angular2+

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am in E: directory.

My global cli version is 7.2.3 checked through  window + cmd and ng --version.

However, when I am checking inside different folders inside E: drive it is showing different cli version like 7.1.1 and 6.0.8 etc: However, I am not inside any angular project.

I am creating a new folder inside E: drive and inside that folder checking ng --version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global ng version would be visible everywhere except for places where you have a local version which is different to the global one.

in your question, when you go to a new folder, you will get the global version **7.2.3** as a result of `ng --version` or `ng --v`

if there is a folder with an old or different version of angular-cli (compared to the global version 7.2.3), then you will see that particular local version, in your case **6.0**. This folder doesn't necessarily needs to be an Angular project, it just needs to have node_modules with @angular and other folders in it.

To verify
 - go to any folder and do `ng --v` 
 - now let's install @angular/cli verison 6.0.0 via `npm install @angular/cli@6.0.0` 
 - now, in the same folder, do `ng --v` 
 - you'll see the version you installed